# Outlook Replacing Text In {LINK} -

Tags: vba, replace, outlook, find

I'm trying to find and replace part of a LINK text in the body of an outlook template.

```
Sub CreateFromTemplate()

last_week = InputBox("Enter date for last week (mm.dd-mm.dd)")
Dim body As String

' ELT

  Dim ELTMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set ELTMail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("F:\AOtter\Outlook Templates\Metric Weeklies\ELT.oft")

body = myMessage.body
body = Replace(body,"07.27-08.02",last_week)

ELTMail.Display
End Sub
```

Example link from Outlook email:

{LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "\\tlnfile\users\AOtter\Metric Mondays\Results\2015.xlsx" **07.27-08.02**!R4C9:R8C13 \a \f 4 \h}

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Am I unable to access the inside of the link with a find and replace/are my operations wrong to access that?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 Dim last_week as string
```

Have you broken it down?

try

```
body = myMessage.body
debug.print body
debug.print  Replace(body,"07.27-08.02","TRYTHIS")
body = Replace(body,"07.27-08.02","TRYTHIS")
debug.print body
```

as you would expect this works:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim body As String

    body = "{LINK Excel.Sheet.12 ""\\tlnfile\users\AOtter\Metric Mondays\Results\2015.xlsx"" 07.27-08.02!R4C9:R8C13 \a \f 4 \h}"
    Debug.Print Replace(body, "07.27-08.02", "fred")

End Sub
```

Comment: I get either a duplicate declaration error (If I include the input box) or a object required error if I don't...

Comment: Have you got Option Explicit at the top of your module? If not  add it.  Where else is last_week  declared?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, y'all.

```
ELTMail.HTMLBody = Replace(ELTMail.HTMLBody, "07.27-08.02", last_week)
```

How silly of me. Of course that would be it. Sorry for the the trouble!!
AO